# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. possibly build.gradle problem

Tags: react-native, gradle

I keep getting this error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

whenever I do react-native run-android. My suspicion is I screwed up something in one of the two build.gradle(s)

Error log: (cmd)

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where: Build file 'D:\Programs\reactnative\tokobangun\android\app\build.gradle' line:
103

* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not find method android() for arguments [build_52alt8ebvpuajag0a3orrbaix$_run_closure1@36f24a11] on project
':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I tried:

1. react-native run-android
2. gradlew clean

Both give me same results.

android/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

/** . . . */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**. . . */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tokobangun"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

I do think I screwed up android/build.gradle somewhere, and I tried to bring it back to how it was when it has no errors, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Oh, if you find my question format lacking, kindly tell me so, I'll adjust it as much as I can. Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0):

in android / build.gradle change the classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0") to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' and try again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work. It gives the exact same error log when I run react-native run-android after I changed it to 3.3.0